# Why shouldn't batch normalisation layers be learnable during fine-tuning?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, tensorflow, transfer-learning, batch-normalization, fine-tuning

I have been reading [this TensorFlow tutorial on transfer learning](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/transfer_learning), where they unfroze the whole model and then they say:

> When you unfreeze a model that contains `BatchNormalization` layers in order to do fine-tuning, you should keep the `BatchNormalization` layers in inference mode by passing `training=False` when calling the base model. Otherwise the updates applied to the non-trainable weights will suddenly destroy what the model has learned.

My question is: why? The model's weights are adapting to the new data, so why do we keep the old mean and variance, which was calculated on ImageNet? This is very confusing.